# In Laravel what is the best way to replace id's with Names in a table relationship on a list of records?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I load the deals index page, Laravel Eloquent has an error

```
**Property [client] does not exist on this collection instance.**
```

Whilst a single record is working perfectly.

---

I have two controller methods using the same Deal model.

On the method that returns the single result my code is working and it returns the data I need. It looks like ....

```
    public function show(Deal $deal)
{
    $deal->client;
    $deal->contact;
    $deal->user;

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $deal,
    ]);
}
```

However the index which returns the list of all deals shows the error. It looks like this ....

```
    public function index()
{
    
   $deals = Deal::all();

   $deals->client;

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $deals,
    ]);
}
```

**Property [client] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Removing the $deals->client; and the controller returns the data but with the ID fields and not the names I want to display. I understand the error as the collection isn't returning the relationship information. How can I get it to do so? or as I have 2 other joins to do What is the most performant way to replace id's with Names in laravel for a situation like this index page?

I'm presuming it has something do to with $deals = Deal::all(); the deal model has the

```
    public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

---

UPDATE: I have it working if I add to the model

```
    public function getClientNameAttribute() {
    if (!empty($this->client)) {
        return $this->client->name;
    }

    return null;
}
```

and the controller looks like ....

```
    public function index()
{

    $deals = Deal::all();

    $deals->each(function ($deal) {
        $deal->append('ClientName');
    });

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $deals,
    ]);
}
```

However I still have 2 more joins to do and this doesn't seem very efficient, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't use it like `$deals->client;` because `$deals` is an array. So you have to use `foreach` loop to get your result

Answer (score 1):

Here you can't access $deals->client because $deals contains multiple collection in order to access client you have to loop

```
 public function index()
{
    
   $deals = Deal::all();

   $deals->client;

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $deals,
    ]);
}
```

Try like this:

```
 public function index()
{

    $deals = Deal::with('client')->get();

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $deals,
    ]);
}
```

You can accesss client like this

```
 foreach($deals as $v)
    {
    dd($v->client)
    
    }
```